# How to import custom classes from model to view controller in adf?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i have some custom classes in model layer in adf.
    i want to use them in view controller but i cannot import them.

how is this possible?
my jdev version is 11.1.1.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click your ViewController project > Project properties > Dependencies > Select Model and click the pencil.
Here you select 'Build output' and press OK twice.
Rebuild your application and you should be able to access classes from your model in your viewcontroller.